# Pinia with VueUse useLocalStorage + useSessionStorage Hybrid?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, pinia, vueuse

I have a button hooked up to a boolean state field coming from Pinia using the vueUse  'useLocalStorage' simplified as:

```
import { defineStore }        from 'pinia'
import { useLocalStorage }    from "@vueuse/core"

export const useDemoStore = defineStore('DemoStore',
{ 
   state: () => 
   ({
      showWords:  useLocalStorage('showWords',true)
   }),
   actions:
   {
       toggleButton(name)
       {
           let newValue = !this[name]
           this[name] = newValue
       }, etc.
    }
}
```

This works fine as the state, which controls a portion of the UI, is cached between sessions, which is what I want. Unfortunately, if you have 2 or more browser tabs / windows open at the same time, the toggle updates the state of all of them as their reactive state is tied to a global variable. This is not what I want. They need to be independent but persist the current state as the default. 'Last in wins' is fine.

Switching this to 'useSessionState' fixes the multi-browser problem but then the state is not persisted to the next use. What I really need is a hybrid solution that limits the state to the current session but saves the default to LocalStorage.

To see what I am talking about, open two or more browser tabs to https://vueuse.org/core/useStorage/ and consider the 'banana' field as **a search term**. Update it to a different value. The field updates to the same value in all the other tabs.  You want to persist this value to a future session as the default but you don't want the other tab instances to change their current value.

A couple of ways come to mind to do this but is there already a built-in or easy way to do this either with existing functionality in the Pinia store or with current VueUse functions?

Comment: It's unclear what's your case exactly and how it's supposed to work.  You can see there's listenToStorageChanges option that's responsible for how storage works for multiple tabs, possibly this is what you look for. You described something like it's a common problem but it's not. Consider explaining in detail what's the current behaviour and what's the desired one.

Comment: I guess what you want is to store the boolean to localStorage only when you finish the session (so when you close a tab?). You could use `window.onbeforeunload` event for this. Then read it when the app starts, but do not bind it to your store directly.

Comment: @Kapcash - It does not need to be at session end. I added an example to hopefully show the issue more clearly.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to persist the value, but not to be synced during the session, the only way I see to do this is to load & save the value when you open / close a tab. So each tab has its own state, but still persist the value at the end for futur sessions.

Example:

```html
<script setup>
import { toRaw } from 'vue'
import { useLocalStorage } from '@vueuse/core'

// this one is synced
const showWords = useLocalStorage('showWords', true)
// local copy of the value, not synced to localStorage
const showWordsLocal = ref(toRaw(showWords))

// you can update `showWordsLocal` freely without impacting the localStorage, so the other tabs


window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
  // Persist in localStorage the current value, only when the tab is closed
  // Feel free to use any other events, maybe Vue onUnmounted?
  showWords.value = showWordsLocal.value
});
</script>
```